# Difference between nat_pairs() and (nat_pairs()) in parameter list

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am beginner with SML and just writing my first functions.

The function is supposed to generate a stream of pairs with natural numbers not containing zero.

This function using filter with a predicate to remove pairs with one of its members zero creates a syntax error:

```
fun nat_pairs_not_zero ()  =  filters not_zero nat_pairs();

stdIn:56.20-59.1 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: (int * int) sequ
  operand:         unit -> (int * int) sequ
  in expression:
    (filters nicht_null) nat_pairs
```

If I first execute nat_pairs and store its result and use just the result, it works.

```
fun nat_pairs_not_zero ()  =  let 
                                   val lst = nat_pairs() 
                              in
                                   filters not_null lst 
                              end;
```

If I add additional braces around `nat_pairs` it works, too.

```
fun nat_pairs_not_zero ()  =  filters not_zero (nat_pairs());
```

If I execute just `(nat_pairs())` and `nat_pairs()`, both give me the same output:

```
val x = CONS ((0,0),fn) : (int * int) sequ
```

Can someone explain me the difference between the version with and without braces?

**Function definitions needed to try**

```
type ’a lazy = unit -> ’a;

fun force (f:’a lazy) = f ();

datatype ’a sequ = NIL 
                 | CONS of ’a * ’a sequ lazy;

fun filters p NIL = NIL
  | filters p (CONS (x,r)) =
       if p x then CONS (x,fn ()=>filters p (force r))
       else filters p (force r);                

fun next_pair (x,0) = CONS ((0,x+1), fn ()=>next_pair((0,x+1)))
  | next_pair (x, y) = CONS ((x+1,y-1), fn ()=>next_pair(x+1,y-1));

fun nat_pairs () = CONS ( (0,0), fn()=>next_pair((0,0)));

fun not_zero (0,b) = false
  | not_zero (a,0) = false
  | not_zero (a,b) = true;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that white space is irrelevant, so

```
filters not_zero nat_pairs()
```

is the same as

```
filters not_zero nat_pairs ()
```

and since application associates to the left, this would parenthesise as

```
((filters not_zero) nat_pairs) ()
```

So, `()` is the third argument to `filters`, not one to `nat_pairs`.

Comment: Ok, to fully understand, why can't I then use `filters(not_zero, nat_pairs())`? This would also make it clear that both not_zero and nat_pairs() are parameter.

Comment: You can, if you define it like `fun filters(p, NIL) = ... | filters(p, CONS(x,r)) = ...` Then `filters` has a different type, namely one of the shape `X * Y -> Z` instead of `X -> Y -> Z`. The former is called tupled form, the latter 'curried' form. Whatever learning material you use will probably discuss these forms at some point.